# Django: presenting in template an average of a foreign key model specific field

Tags: python, django

My system include 2 models one for items and second for reviews of these items. In every review there are many different fields (how fun it is, how friendly etc..)

I'm trying to query the DB so I can present say the average score of friendly (which is a field in Review) of the festival i'm currently in (I guess by PK). Since I'm new to Django this task is a little bit confusing for me. Appreciate your help.

Models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
...

class Review(models.Model):

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('festival_list:single', args=[self.festival.pk])

item = models.ForeignKey(
    Item,
    related_name='Item_Reviews',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=False,
    blank = False,
)
bad = 0
okay = 1
good = 2
great = 3
superb = 4
score_choices = (
    (0, 'Bad'),
    (1, 'Okay'),
    (2, 'Good'),
    (3, 'Great'),
    (4, 'Superb'),
)
friendly = models.IntegerField(
    choices=score_choices,
    default=score_choices[0],
)
```

Views.py:

```
class DetailItem(generic.DetailView):
queryset = models.Item.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DetailItem, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['item_reviews'] = models.Review.objects.all()
    return context
```

Item_detail.html:

```
<h4>Friendly</h4>
<p>
 {% for score in item_reviews %}
   {{ ?? }}  
 {% endfor %}
 </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the average with an *aggregate*:

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DetailItem, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # ...
    context['avg_friendly'] = self.object.Item_Reviews.aggregate(
        avg_friendly=Avg('friendly')
    )['avg_friendly']
    # ...
    return context
```

or shorter:

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DetailItem, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # ...
    context.update(self.object.Item_Reviews.aggregate(
        avg_friendly=Avg('friendly')
    ))
    # ...
    return context
```

Here `self.object.Item_Reviews` will thus give the *related* `Review`s for the given object (the sepected `Item`).

So here the context contains a variable `avg_friendly` that contains the average for the `friendly` view for *related* reviews.

You can thus render this with:

```
{{ avg_friendly }}
```

In case there are no related reviews, the average will be `None`, so we can use the [**`default_if_none`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none):

```
{{ avg_friendly|default_if_none:"no reviews yet" }}
```